# Ember model not updated

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route that displays a list of challenges, when I create a new challenge the record is persisted however the model of list of challenges is not updated when I transition back into the route. Is there something I am missing?

```
//new.js
 var challenge = this.store.createRecord('challenge', {
            name_en: this.get('model.name_en'),
            name_fr: this.get('model.name_fr'),
            description_en: this.get('model.description_en'),
            description_fr: this.get('model.description_fr'),
            end_date: this.get('model.end_date'),
            start_date: this.get('model.start_date'),
            points_cap: this.get('model.points_cap'),
            points_goal: this.get('model.points_goal'),
            challenge_type: 1,
            short_description_en: this.get('model.short_description_en'),
            short_description_fr: this.get('model.short_description_fr'),
            excluded_activities: excluded
        });

        // Persist record.
        challenge.save().then((challenge) => {
            this.transitionToRoute('challenges');
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.handleError(error, 'error.system_error');
        });

//router.js
Router.map(function() {
   this.route('challenges', function() {
   this.route('new');
   this.route('challenge', {
    path: ':challenge_id'
}, function() {
   this.route('delete');
   this.route('edit');
});
```

});

```
//challenges.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import UserProfile from '../models/user-profile';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{

userProfile: UserProfile.create(),

model: function() {
    return this.store.query('challenge', {league_id: this.get('userProfile.league_id')});
}
```

});

```
//new challenge payload
 {  
"activity_exclusion_list":[  

],
"challenge_type":1,
"challengeUrl":null,
"end_date":"31-10-2015",
"number_participants":null,
"number_teams":null,
"points_cap":null,
"points_goal":null,
"start_date":"01-10-2015",
"leagueId":"1",
"teams":[  

],
"name_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge ",
  "fr":null
},
"description_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge",
  "fr":null
},
"short_description_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge",
  "fr":null
}
```

}

```
//response from new challenge
{  
"challenge_type":"Individual",
"description":" ",
"description_fr":null,
"description_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge",
  "fr":null
},
"challengeUrl":" ",
"start_date":"01-10-2015",
"end_date":"31-10-2015",
"name":" ",
"name_fr":null,
"name_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge ",
  "fr":null
},
"points_cap":0,
"points_goal":0,
"short_description":" ",
"short_description_fr":null,
"short_description_lang":{  
  "en":"New Challenge",
  "fr":null
},
"number_participants":0,
"number_teams":0,
"teams":[  

],
"challenge_id":265,
"activity_exclusion_list":[  

],
"leagueId":1
```

}

Comment: At first glance it seems to be ok. Can you provide your challenges route to see how you are retrieving the model?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using `this.store.query` because `league_id` is not your principal id, right? then, in your `createRecord`, where are you setting `league_id`?

Comment: I missing challenge.set('league', league) in the code I pasted in. That sets the league id that gets assign on the challenge. From what I can tell the model hook is not called on challenges is not called back after I save the new record. I try doing this this.get('challenges.model').pushObject(challenge._internalModel) that updates the list however it causes me problem when I want to delete that record

Comment: Can you post your payload while saving and your server response? I'm not sure yet, but I think you have to set `id` in your `createRecord`.

Comment: I added both payload, the server returns a challenge_id witch gets map to the primary key

Comment: Are you using the ember inspector in your browser? is the model in data updated after a save?

Comment: Yes after creating a new record its appearing in the data section of the Ember Inspector

Comment: FYI a developer from Ember Data found my problem. My issue was caused because I was using the this.store.query method to retrieve the list of challenges. This method does not listen for new records added to the store. To fix it changed it to used this.store.filter

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your challenges route have you tried using a `this.store.filter` instead? The issue could be that the query function only returns a RecordArray, whereas filter returns a Live RecordArray which will update your templates and everything else when the promise (in this case the successful save) is resolved.

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.filter('challenge', {league_id: this.get('userProfile.league_id')}, function() {
      // We're not actually filtering, so just return true for everything
      return true;
    });
}
```

I had the same problem and this turned out to be the solution, hope it helps!

[Ember Docs reference](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter)

Comment: Thanks that exactly what was my problem