# How to update model data when store is updated emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I know Controllers are deprecated now in Ember, but I would like know how I would achieve this using older version of ember.

I have a route defined as follows:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
         return Ember.RSVP.hash({
             posts : store.find('post', {date : params.date, page : params.page})
         });
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        this.set('model', model.posts);
    }
});
```

Everything works fine and the data gets loaded. Now I've decided to load data dynamically from controller. So in the corresponding controller, I did as below:

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    Ember.RSVP.hash({
             posts : store.find('post', {date : params.date, page : params.page})
    }).then(function(data) {
        this.store.pushPayLoad(this.store.modelFor('post'), data); 
    }.bind(this));
});
```

In the above way, I was able to get the data loaded in Ember Store but it is not loaded into the model. What is the recommended way so that the model gets updated as soon as the data is available in the store.

Comment: Array controllers are deprecated.

Comment: My bad. But currently I'm stuck with using an older version of ember :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify: why do you want to move things to the controller?

It seems that the simplest way to go about all of this would be to get rid off all of that ArrayController code, as well as the setupController method in the route, and just set the model as follows:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
         return this.store.find('post', {date : params.date, page : params.page});

    }
});
```

This is Ember's preferred (and expected) way of fetching a model with params.

To simplify things even more, and assuming your params are formatted as follows:

```
{
  date: SOME_DATE,
  page: SOME_PAGE
}
```

Then all you need to do is the following:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
         return this.store.find('post', params);
    }
});
```

That will find all of the posts with the given params, and assign them to the model, which will then be available as `{{model}}` in your template and `this.get('model');` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you  much. You did help me understand few nuances. Also, I want the model to be updated if the store gets updated. I'm doing a lazy load essentially in the controller and correspondingly using this.store.pushPayload() to update the posts. Do I have to explicitly set the model in controller every time I do this lazy load?

Comment: I can't say for certain without seeing the code unfortunately, but you shouldn't need to redefine the model at all.

What I can say is that you should check out [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32997926/1431452) for a bit more info on how to keep the model up to date any time the store is updated.